# Using www subdomain causes 404 error

Tags: apache, tomcat, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm using Apache HTTPD in front of Apache Tomcat with the following virtual host:

```xml
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/onlinetaskboarddotcom 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin comented@out.com
    ServerName www.onlinetaskboard.com
    ServerAlias onlinetaskboard.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/www/apache/onlinetaskboarddotcom

    ProxyPass / http://www.onlinetaskboard.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://www.onlinetaskboard.com:8080/

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/www/apache/onlinetaskboarddotcom/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The URLs without `www` subdomain like `onlinetaskboard.com/login` and `onlinetaskboard.com/someOtherValidPage` work fine, however once I include the `www` subdomain like `www.onlinetaskboard.com`, then I get a 404 error in some browsers like Chrome.

Here are the request/response headers which I observed in Chrome.

With `www` subdomain:

```
Request:
        Request URL:http://www.onlinetaskboard.com/
        Request Method:GET
        Status Code:404 Not Found
Request headers:
        Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
        Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
        Connection:keep-alive
        Cookie:JSESSIONID=DE44F60835D23E6AB3CC2A2E8B9D6279
        Host:www.onlinetaskboard.com
        User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/28.0.1500.71 Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
Response headers:
        Connection:Keep-Alive
        Content-Encoding:gzip
        Content-Length:377
        Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
        Date:Thu, 14 Nov 2013 23:39:24 GMT
        Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
        Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
        Vary:Accept-Encoding
        X-Pad:avoid browser bug
```

And without the `www` subdomain:

```
Request:    
        Request URL:http://onlinetaskboard.com/
        Request Method:GET
        Status Code:302 Found
Request Headers:
        Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
        Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
        Cache-Control:max-age=0
        Connection:keep-alive
        Cookie:JSESSIONID=36D1DED5A3F7B5E185FE5D5EDD4457FC
        Host:onlinetaskboard.com
        User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/28.0.1500.71 Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
Response headers:
        Connection:Keep-Alive
        Content-Length:0
        Date:Fri, 15 Nov 2013 00:04:33 GMT
        Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
        Location:http://onlinetaskboard.com/login
        Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?